# mysql query, slow performance on select or update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a queue table that is updated and selected frequently (8 concurrent threads). The operation of each thread is:

```
- count for queue_process_id
- count == 0, update 10 new items with queue_process_id = N
- select and search for queue_process_id
```

The queue table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `queue` (
  `queue_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `queue_module_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `queue_action` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `queue_value` text NOT NULL,
  `queue_value2` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `queue_priority` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `queue_order` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `queue_process_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '99',
  PRIMARY KEY (`queue_id`),
  KEY `queue_priority` (`queue_priority`),
  KEY `queue_module_id` (`queue_module_id`),
  KEY `queue_action` (`queue_action`),
  KEY `queue_order` (`queue_order`),
  KEY `queue_process_id` (`queue_process_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2502029 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

This is the query used for updating new items:

```
update queue set queue_process_id = N where queue_module_id = N and queue_process_id = 99 order by queue_priority desc limit 10
```

queue_module_id is for different modules. Each module has N threads, all of them are using the same table.

This the result for the EXPLAIN statement (update switched to select):

```
mysql> explain select SQL_NO_CACHE  * from queue where queue_module_id = 1 and queue_process_id = 99 order by queue_priority desc limit 10;

    +----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
    | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                    | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
    +----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | queue | index | queue_module_id,queue_process_id | queue_priority | 2       | NULL |   20 | Using where |
    +----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

The update statement needs up to 13 seconds (!) to finish. I have no idea how to optimize the query or the indexes. Maybe someone can help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `update` query:

```
update queue
    set queue_process_id = N
    where queue_module_id = N and queue_process_id = 99
    order by queue_priority desc
    limit 10;
```

(I assume the `N` is a place holder, because it lacks quotes needed for a constant.)

You can speed this with an index.  The best index is on `queue(queue_module_id, queue_process_id, queue_priority)`.  You can create this using:

```
create index idx_queue_3 on queue(queue_module_id, queue_process_id, queue_priority)
```

Comment: Great answer. CPU from 100% to 0-2%. I really have to look into indexes. Thank you.